# How to upgrade graphlab create?

Tags: ipython, graphlab

I want to know where to paste this command

```
pip install graphlab-create==1.6.1
```

so that it can upgrade my graphlab create.

I use windows 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should type this in your terminal. If you have installed it using the Dato Launcher, then you can get access to the terminal by clicking on the "Terminal" icon.